How run the expo project?
I have react-native project. But it's built long ago, and use expo. Now I can't run the project because version is not correct. How can I fix it?
I reinstalled SDK and expo, and node modules, but I can't run it.
they have the error like Unexpected tokens

what's the error message? bonus: is it for upwork?

Expo recently updated their SDK to v51 so unless you're using an emulator on a mac device you'll need to update your version of expo to the latest version.
Here is a tutorial from the website but i'll break it down below: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Update your version of Expo in your react-native root directory
npm install expo@latest

Upgrade all dependencies to match the installed SDK version.
npx expo install --fix


You should be good to go. Good luck.
